# Stop music playback when I lock the screen

Tags: music, kde

Is it possible to run `xmms2 stop` when I lock the screen with <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+L</kbd>?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be.

The desktop-agnostic way is:

- install xbindkeys
- create a script that runs your "xmms" command plus "xscreensaver -l" or "kdescreensaver --lock"
- create a `~/.xbindkeysrc`
- make xbindkeys run at startup

Assuming your script is in `/usr/local/bin/lockandstop`, `~/.xbindkeysrc` should contain:

```
"/usr/local/bin/lockandstop"
Control + Alt + l
```

or perhaps

```
"/usr/local/bin/lockandstop"
Mod4 + l
```

depending on what `xmodmap` prints.

But maybe the KDE Control Panel offers an easier way under the keyboard shortcuts section.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. I just can't find kdescreensaver. Is that the correct command for KDE 4.5?

Comment: Found a solution via DBus: http://tips4linux.com/lock-your-kde-screen-from-the-command-line/