# Is there any way to stop music when locking the screen?

Tags: windows, music, foobar2000

I use Foobar2000 on Windows and I would like it to stop playing when I lock the screen.
How to do that? There is [a previous thread](https://superuser.com/questions/231677/stop-music-playback-when-i-lock-the-screen) that answers that for linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install the following component: http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_lock